ROS2 Navg Issue Help
ROS distro Humble
Ubuntu 22.04
Navigation (SLAM, Nav2 etc.)
Expected behaviour
Hi, I'm using ROS 2 Humble and I'm mapping with the Slamtec S2 Lidar. I want to use a path in the map I generated, but whenever I run ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py, I keep getting the following error spam. I can t solve that problem search much times tried things on web, still same issue ı got.
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1721746007.538392027] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser' at time 1721746007.138 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1721746007.638511430] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser' at time 1721746007.238 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'

It does not seems an error, Just an info. Try to use arg use_sim_time :=True at the end of your launch file if you're running a simulation or set False if you're running in real robot. It's very common these warnings of old or early TF transform and mismatch of timestamps, since a lidar sends million of points per second...
If you think this is the issue, you can try changing your QoS reliability, durability on rviz2 and in costmaps which subscribe this scan data.
You didn't put the log or error of the path Planning, and any images of what is going on. Then it is a little bit hard to diagnose the issue. If is on transform, on planner, on nav2 configuration, on QoS...or in the map resolution (it also affects the planner functionality if too high or too low)....
